# TSQL remove decimal under certain condition

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a problem with a database in which a user has inputted a decimal where a comma would go on a frequent basis.  I will work on correcting the issue going forward but need to fix the 100 plus records already entered.  Its a mix of correct location and incorrect locations

Small example:

```
153.30
129.30
152.709
153.308
108.777
21.369
```

I want to preserve the entries where the decimal is indicating cents, and remove the decimal where it should have been a comma to look like such.

```
153.30
129.30
152709
153308
108777
21369
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the column? If it is decimal and the user originally entered `1.000` instead of `1,000` this will be stored as `1` and there will be no way of knowing this. Similarly if they entered `1.230` instead of `1,230` it will be stored as `1.23`

Comment: Datatype of the column is money, null

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going to have a real hard time here, and it may be quickest to just spot check the 100 rows and fix them manually. Here's why:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(m MONEY);

INSERT @x SELECT 153.30  UNION ALL SELECT 153.300;

SELECT m FROM @x;
```

Results:

```
m
------
153.30
153.30
```

SQL Server will present those to you as identical. I couldn't figure out a way to convert to a string (or binary, or any other type), either implicitly or explicitly, to tell those two values apart once they arrived in the table.

Now, you may be able to narrow it down, for the three-digit decimals that *don't* end in zero:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(m MONEY);

INSERT @x SELECT 153.30  UNION ALL SELECT 153.300
UNION ALL SELECT 153.309 UNION ALL SELECT 24.125;

SELECT m FROM @x WHERE m * 1000 % 10 > 0;
```

Results:

```
m
-------
153.309
 24.125
```

But for the ones that end in zero, you're on your own. So, fix the data, slap the user's wrist, and move on.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #tt (value varchar(18))
insert into #tt select '153.30'
insert into #tt select '152.709'

select * from
#tt
where len(replace(substring(value,Charindex('.',value),999),'.','')) > 2
```

I think this could help you, i make this example with a varchar type, and with convert maybe will help to find the ones that need to be updated.